# The React Bootstrap dropdown menu is not closing instead gets rendered horizontally

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, react-bootstrap

So I was using react-bootstrap dropdown menu and i found a bug that it doesn't close .It actually renders all its options horizontally on my screen.

I searched over Stackoverflow .There were few resembling posts but none of them is for react

```
        <DropdownButton
          title={this.state.selectedOption}
          id="document-type"
          onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
        >
          {myoptions.map((opt, i) => (
            <Dropdown.Item key={i} eventKey={i}>
              {opt}
            </Dropdown.Item>
          ))}`enter code here`
        </DropdownButton>
```

I expected Nomral Behavior

Comment: well did you import bootstrap css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/),

> Dropdowns are toggleable, contextual overlays for displaying lists of links and more. Like overlays, Dropdowns are built using a third-party library Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection.

Also you need to add `bootstrap.css`, either by adding `link` in `index.html`

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
```

or by importing in `index.js` file.

Add `popper` in `index.html`

```
<script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-sw55v?fontsize=14)

Comment: The problem was that it somehow inherited some css from parent elements and was causing problems . Thanks for response